# social auth django: disconnect vs disconnect_individual

Tags: python, django, oauth, python-social-auth

So I have added the [disconnection pipeline](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#disconnection-pipeline) to my application using [`python-social-auth`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django). I noticed that there are two endpoints in the [`urls.py`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/master/social_django/urls.py#L22):

- **disconnect** - `/oauth/disconnect/<backend>/`
- **disconnect_individual** - `oauth/disconnect/<backend>/<association_id>/`

Where `backend` could refer to the social provider (`facebook`, `google-plus`, `linkedin`, ...).

Through my experiments, I find that the first endpoint, **disconnect**, will remove the logged in user's associated `UserSocialAuth` table entry.

**What does the second endpoint do?**

**What does the `association_id` represent?**

Is it a way of dissociating one individual account if the user has two `UserSocialAuth` entries with the same backend? That doesn't make sense since the `uid` + `provider` [must be unique](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/master/social_django/models.py#L73). Can someone provide an example of when one would call the **disconnect_individual**?

Answer (score 0):

The `disconnect_individual` endpoint purpose is to let users remove a single integration account, take for instance a page where the user gets the list of all the associated accounts to your project, and this user will be able to remove a particular one.

The `association_id` is the `UserSocialAuth` id in the database.

Comment: I was under the impression that uid + provider [must be unique](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/master/social_django/models.py#L73). Are you saying that this endpoint is for when a user has two accounts with the same provider?

Comment: That's true, `uid + provider` must be unique, but this endpoint is not just for that case, the user could disconnect any associated account.